# How could I remove trailing blank lines on save, in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to remove trailing blank lines (blank lines could also be just a bunch of tabs and spaces).

In my `.vimrc` I have:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$## " trim white spaces at the end of file
```

This works, however if a file has already had its trailing blank lines removed, I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing BufWrite Auto commands for "*":
```

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:help :s_flags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#:s_flags):

```
[e]     When the search pattern fails, do not issue an error message.
```

So you could try:

```
:%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$##e
```